# How do I add prefix for elements' attributes using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am stuck on how to add prefix **ext:** for my attributes. I would like to add ext to approximateDateIndicator, currentIndicator, DateOfBirthIndicator so they look like this:
**ext:approximateDateIndicator **ext:currentIndicator** **ext:DateOfBirthIndicator**

My xslt has a namespace **xmlns:ext="http://www.courts.state.dc.us/ProtectionOrderExtension/1.0"**.

**My output is not adding the ext:**

```
<ext:PersonBirthDate>
    <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="false" currentIndicator="false" DateOfBirthIndicator="true">1988-09-01</ext:PersonBirthDate>
    <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="false" currentIndicator="false" DateOfBirthIndicator="true">1988-09-02</ext:PersonBirthDate>
    <ext:PersonBirthDate approximateDateIndicator="false" currentIndicator="true" DateOfBirthIndicator="true">1990-01-01</ext:PersonBirthDate>
    </ext:PersonBirthDate>
```

**My xslt code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ext="http://www.courts.state.Dc.us/ProtectionOrderExtension/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="ProtectionOrder">
        <ext:ProtectionOrder>
            <xsl:variable name="vProtectionOrderID">
                <xsl:value-of select="@InternalProtectionOrderID"/>
            </xsl:variable>
    <!--Respondent -->
            <xsl:for-each select="RespondentPartyID">
                <xsl:for-each select="//CaseParty[(@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID) and (Connection[(@Word='RSP') ])]">
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
                        <xsl:call-template name="Respondent">
                            <xsl:with-param name="pProtectionOrderID">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$vProtectionOrderID"/>
                            </xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ext:ProtectionOrder>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Template for DateOfBirth for the respondent-->
    <xsl:template match="DateOfBirth">
        <ext:PersonBirthDate>
            <xsl:attribute name="approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="currentIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="DateOfBirthIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(.))"/>
        </ext:PersonBirthDate>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--Template for DateOfBirth or the respondent where Current = true -->
    <xsl:template match="DateOfBirth[@Current='true']">
        <ext:PersonBirthDate>
            <xsl:attribute name="approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="currentIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="DateOfBirthIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(.))"/>
        </ext:PersonBirthDate>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--Template for ApproximateDOB for the respondent-->
    <xsl:template match="ApproximateDOB">
        <ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="true" ext:currentIndicator="{not(../DateOfBirth)}" ext:DateOfBirthIndicator="false">
            <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(.))"/>
        </ext:PersonBirthDate>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--Respondent Template-->
    <xsl:template name="Respondent">
        <xsl:param name="pProtectionOrderID"/>
        <ext:Respondent>
            <ext:PersonRaceCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="//CaseParty[@ID=current()/@ID]/ObservedRace/@Word"/>
            </ext:PersonRaceCode>
    <!--Guardian -->
            <xsl:for-each select="//CaseParty[(Connection[(@Word='GRD')])][1]">
                <xsl:for-each select="//Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="Guardian"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- This is the date of birth of the respondent which is based on the 3 templates above (ApproximateDOB, DateOfBirth[@Current='true'] and DateOfBirth  -->
            <ext:PersonBirthDate>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ApproximateDOB|DateOfBirth"/>
            </ext:PersonBirthDate>
        </ext:Respondent>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--Guardian Template-->
    <xsl:template name="Guardian">
        <ext:Guardian>
            <xsl:for-each select="Race">
                <ext:PersonRaceCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Word"/>
                </ext:PersonRaceCode>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ext:Guardian>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My xml code**

```
<Party ID="76">
        <Gender Word="F ">Female</Gender>
        <NotifyElectronically>0</NotifyElectronically>
        <NeedsInterpreter>false</NeedsInterpreter>
        <PartyInJailFlag>false</PartyInJailFlag>
        <ApproximateDOB>3/4/1956</ApproximateDOB>
        <DateOfBirth>04/21/1956</DateOfBirth>
        <DateOfBirth Current="true">05/21/1956</DateOfBirth>
</Party>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your namespace is already declared and assigned a prefix, all you need to do is add the prefix when specifying the name of the attribute:

Instead of:

```
<xsl:attribute name="approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
```

write:

```
<xsl:attribute name="ext:approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
```

etc.

Comment: @user3781064 I cannot reproduce your issue. Unfortunately, I cannot use your code to show you that, because it has other problems: the ext: prefix in the XML input is not bound to a namespace, and neither is the mscef: prefix in the XSLT. But have a look at the simplified demo here:http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaF4